# Integration and little o notation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f,g : [0, \infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ such that $$f (x) = o(g(x))$$  that is, $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0.$

1) Is it true that $$\int_0^x f(t) dt = o(\int_0^x g(t) dt) \ ?$$ Prove or give counterexample ?

2)If it is not true, what condition should be added to $g(x)$ such that little o preserve under integration ?

1) Since it asks some conditions on no.2, I think that no.1 should be false. But I cannot think of examples. Simple functions : $e^x,$ polynomial, $\log x, \sin x, \cos x, \frac{1}{x^m}$ do not work (I try somes combination of them). I guess the example might be something more complicated and connect to analysis.

Any hints on how to build functions ?

2) Suppose I want to show that $$\lim \frac{F(x)}{G(x)} = 0$$ where $F, G$ denote the corresponding antiderivative of $f ,g$ without invoke any more condition on $g$.

One thing is $G(x)$ should not be $0$. Since $g$ is positive, I think this clearly confirm that $G(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$.

If the condition is true, for any $\epsilon > 0$, it must exist $M > 0$ such that $$F(x) < \epsilon G(x)$$ for any $x > M$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f = o(g)$, there exist $M$ such that $f(x) < \epsilon g(x)$ for $x > M.$

So $$\int_0^x f(t) dt < \int_0^x \epsilon g(t) dt$$ for any $x > M.$ Seem like I prove it and $g$ does not require anything. However, I feel bad and not sure about this. Seem like it is wrong somewhere, but I am not sure where and why.

Help please.

Comment: For part $(1)$, try $f = e^{-2x}, g = e^{-x}$. Part $(2)$ would work if $G(x) \to \infty$ with $x$ (although I'm not sure if this is the best possible answer).

Comment: My deleted answer was mixing up $g = o(f) $, I apologize.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I dont understand why $e^{-x}, e^{-2x}$ work for the first part. It does not counter the statement, or I do some calculation wrongly ? For part (2), I dont see why I need that condition. Could you please explain a bit how that condition arise ? I try to see where in my proof requires that condition, but not see where.

Comment: $\int_0^x 2e^{-2x} dx = 1 - e^{-2x}$, and $\int_0^x e^{-x} dx = 1-e^{-x}$, so $F/G \to 1/2$. Further, $G(x) \uparrow \infty$ is necessary - if $G(\infty) \in \mathbb{R}$, then try to show that for $f(x) = e^{-x} g(x)$, $F(x)/G(x)>f(0)/G(\infty) >0$. I don't have the time for an answer just now, I'll post one later.

Comment: Your error seems to be here - $\int_0^x f \le \epsilon \int_0^x g$. You can only say that for $x>M$, $\int_M^x f < \epsilon \int_M^x g \implies F(x) < F(M) + \epsilon(G(x) - G(M))$. Getting from here to $F/G \to 0$ requires that the ratio $F(M)/G(x) \to 0$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. I always choose integration constant to be $0$. So that why I wonder how you get the first question. I will try to understand your second statement, and see why this fact is needed in my proof above.

Comment: Ah, but the question is talking about a particular definite integral. You don't have complete control over the integration constant.

Comment: So you think it is fine if I say I will choose $1$ as the constant ? It is alright if you are busy right now. I am not that very hurry, just try to understand the concept, and find where I am missing. Again thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This is not about choosing a constant: you're not computing *primitives*, you're computing *integrals*. When you compute a primitive, you can choose whatever constant you like. When you compute an integral, the integration constant has no role whatsoever: $\int_a^b f = \left[ F \right]_a^b = F(b) - F(a)$. If you were to choose another primitive $F_2 = F + c$, $\int_a^b f = \left[ F_2 \right]_a^b = F(b)  + c - (F(a) + c) = F(b) - F(a)$. When computing *integrals*, there are no constants to choose. You only have to focus on the bounds of your integral.

Comment: @Mariuslp okay, thank you for point that out. I just so silly : $1$ is from $e^0$, not a constant from integration.