# Primitive and derivative of little $o$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, asymptotics

For $x\in {\rm I\!R}$ in a neighborhood of $0$ and $n>1$, we define the function $f(x) = o(x^n)$ and one of its primitives $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$.

Is it true that:

1. $F(x) = o(x^{n+1})$
2. $f'(x) = o(x^{n-1})$

How to prove it? Here are my attempts:

---

1. I need to prove that:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{F(x)}{x^{n+1}} = 0
$$

I tried to develop the fraction :

$$
\frac{F(x)}{x^{n+1}} = \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{x^{n+1}}dt
$$

But I couldn't go further...
A related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934158/integration-and-little-o-notation) seems to add a condition to get this true but I coundn't really understand the comments.

---

2. I would use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) :

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{x^{n-1}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{\frac{x^n}{n}} = 0 
$$

Is it correct ?

Comment: I don't like the expression "we define $f(x) := o(x)$". the little o rapresent a limit of two functions, so you can "consider a function" that is an $ o(x)$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: You can prove them both using L'Hopitals rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the integration of little $o$ is okay, but differentiation is not.

**Differentiation**
Consider the function 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^3\sin{(1/x^4)}\,, & x\neq0\,;\\
0\,, & x = 0\,;
\end{cases}
$$
which is $o(x^2)$ as $x\to0$ (so it satisfies your condition that $n>1$), but $f'(x) = 3x^2\sin{(1/x^4)} - 4x^{-1}\cos{(1/x^4)}\,,$ which is clearly not $o(x)$ as $x\to0\,$.

The moral is that the asymptotic bounds cannot control the wild oscillations.

**Integration**
Suppose $f(x)=o(g(x))$ as $x\to0\,,$ and define $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t\,$, and $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t) \,\mathrm{d}t\,$. By definition of $f(x)=o(g(x))\,$, given any $\epsilon >0\,$, we have that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\big|f(x)\big| \leq \epsilon \,g(x)
$$
whenever $0<x<\delta\,$. We can then estimate
$$
\big|F(x)\big| \leq \int_0^x \big|f(t)\big| \, \mathrm{d}t \leq \epsilon\int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \epsilon \,G(x)\,.
$$
As such we have proved that $F(x) = o(G(x))$ as $x\to0\,$.

Comment: Very nice example for differentiation. +1 In general differentiation destroys desirable properties of a function whereas integration makes them more well behaved.

Comment: +1 and a tiny correction: when differentiating, the second term is $-4x^{-2}\cos(1/x^4)$, rather than $-4x^{-1} \cos(1/x^4)$ (no visible difference, both expressions serve the same purpose. Also, old post, I know, but was looking for such an example and came across this).

Answer (score -1):

In differntiation you misused L'Hopital's rule because:
the limit of the fraction of the derivatives **first has to exist**, if you can prove it's existance only then will it be equal to the limit of the fraction of the main functions.